# C's pow() function as per header file <math.h> not working properly

Tags: c, floating-accuracy

I see that for the following code produces the result as below, any idea on why is the output like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t\t\t%d\t\t\t", i, (int)pow(10, i));    
        printf("%f\n", pow(10, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
0                       1                       1.000000

1                       10                      10.000000

2                       99                      100.000000

3                       1000                    1000.000000

4                       9999                    10000.000000

5                       100000                  100000.000000

6                       1000000                 1000000.000000

7                       9999999                 10000000.000000

8                       99999999                100000000.000000

9                       999999999               1000000000.000000
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of the pow function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/strange-behaviour-of-the-pow-function)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `round()` function before casting to `int`, else the trailing digits will just get truncated.

Answer (score 2):

As with every one of the billion other questions on SO to do with floating point :-), the answer is that not all numbers can be represented exactly.

And, even if they *can* be represented exacly, you may get a bad result from something like `pow` which may work within a loop. In other words, no matter how small the error on an operation, if you do it a lot of times, the error becomes large.

Try printing out the return from `pow(10,4)` with a `%.50f` or other floating point specifier, and I'll guarantee you'll see something like `9999.9999999237623465` instead of `10000`.

For what it's worth, the correct results are produced under gcc 3.4.4 under CygWin so it's likely that you're using a less-exact implementation of `pow`.