# Why am I getting unexpected output when using floor with pow?

Tags: c++, pow, floor

So, I ran this code on my code blocks:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    a=pow(10,9);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    a=ceil(pow(10,9));
    cout<<a<<endl;
    a=floor(pow(10,9));
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got the output as:

```
 999999999
 100000000
 100000000
```

1st output was not 10^9 due to truncation effect,which means that pow(10,9) was something like
999999999.99999.., but then how come floor of this thing is 1000000000 ??

Comment: On my machine it prints `1000000000` three times. See also http://ideone.com/qLIp33

Comment: Welcome to floating point, where _nothing_ is as it seems :-)

Comment: What machine and compiler and OS are you using?  Can you also try printing the three values as hex bytes?

Comment: `pow(10,9)` might be treated differently in the two invocations... for example, on x86 it might be rounded up when converting from an 80-bit register to an intermediate 64-bit `double` value that's the input to `floor`, whereas the to-`int` conversion just truncates.

Comment: The only way to answer your question would be by inspecting the assembler output from the compiler. It may well be that the `trunc(pow(10,9))` is turned into a integer calculation that is precise (multiplying 10 * 10, then that by itself to give 10^4, and again to give 10^8, and then multiply by 10 again - or simply constant folded from something like that), where the compiler isn't making the same optimisation in the first case (for reasons that I don't quite understand, but compilers work in mysterious ways at times)

Comment: my compiler: mingw32-g++, OS is windows 8

Comment: this is probably a bug in the library.  see from the definition http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow.  when you do a = pow(10,9), it uses the integer (long) version, which should not have truncation, floor, or rounding issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the maximum value for `int` is 2,147,483,647, therefore there should be no overflow or truncation (it's an `int`). And my output is exactly:

> 1000000000
>   1000000000
>   1000000000

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c;similar question has already been brought up but here the main concern is with the floor() function misbehaving

Comment: the floor function is not misbehaving.  what is likely the issue is that the pow (long version) misbehaves.