# Why isn't while ((i <= 9) && square == pow(i, 2)) { cout << i << square; i++; printing out as I want it to?

Tags: c++, while-loop, sequence

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {

int i = 0;
int square = 0;

// Write a while loop here:

while ((i <= 9) && square == pow(i, 2)) {
    cout << i << square;
    i++;


}
}

  //Why is this not printing out 
/* 0   0
   1   1
   2   4
   3   9
   4   16
   5   25
   6   36
   7   49
   8   64
   9   81
          */
```

/*Can someone explain to me thoroughly as to why this while loop fails to print out this           sequence of numbers.

I don't understand why this only prints out 00 instead of that list of numbers. Can someone explain to me as why this while loop does not work properly?*/

Comment: `square` is initialized to zero and never again updated. Did you mean to assign it instead...?

Comment: Hello, are you clear with the answers or do you want to understand something more?

Answer (score 3):

You probably wanted to do:

```
while (i <= 9) {
    square = pow(i, 2);
    cout << i << square;
    i++;
}
```

Or:

```
while (i <= 9 && (square = pow(i, 2))) {
    cout << i << square;
    i++;
}
```

Otherwise as soon as the `square == pow(i, 2)` is false the loop is ended and you seem to want to asign square and not compare it

Comment: The second version is incorrect without adding some brackets to fix the precedence issues. And I wouldn't recommend assigning in a loop condition in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
// For version
double square;

for (int i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++) {
    square = pow(i, 2);
    cout << i <<" "<< square <<"\n";
}
```

```
//While version
double square;
int i = 0;

while (i <= 9) {
    square = pow(i, 2);
    cout << i <<" "<< square <<"\n";
    i++;
}
```

**pow** returns answer in **double**.

I have written **double square** because it may happen that for some numbers, the square of it may get truncated/ round off when you are assigning it to integer variable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714115/strange-powx-y-behaviour) for more info.

Comment: Hello @Juan if you are clear with the answer please mark it.. or if you still have any doubts do tell..

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you do not update "square" value in each iteration and it is always equal to zero, and hence your while loop immediately terminates by i = 1, because square = 0 and pow(i,2) = 1 . You should notice that the `square == pow(i,2)` condition does NOT assign the right-hand-side value to square variable. It only compares them. From your desired output I understand that you may want something like this:

```
i = 0;
while (i <= 9) {
    cout << i << "     " << pow(i, 2);
    i++;
}
```