# Checking numbers in an array

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

I want to write a function that returns true if and only if in an array t of size n i have every single number from 1,2, ... n

My idea was to:

```
bool g(int* t, int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = n; j > 0; j--){
           if(t[i] == n)
              break;
           else
              return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However this for  `int t[6] = {6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1};` returns zero which is wrong as all number from 1 to 6 are in an array.

How this could be improved? Furthermore how this question could be improved?

Comment: Sum the array and see if it is equal to `n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: See also: [Triangular Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Comment: @Ics but what if t[6]={1,1,1,1,1,16};

Comment: @Rama thus in fact this solution is not universal... all in all i guess you have to browse through the array but how?

Comment: @Rama Well, while summing, you could check if any number is `> n`, and return `false` in first such occurrence.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius t[6]={1,1,1,6,6,6};

Comment: @Rama Dang it.. I guess, you could find any counter-example to the suggested formula. My first thought was inserting all elements to `std::set`, and then using that, to decide on whether all required elements are present.

Comment: @Rama check that it is also equal to `n!`

Comment: Sort it and then check one by one. Or shove it into a hash map and then check one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool g( const int a[], int n )
{
    int long long sum = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n && a[i] > 0 ; i++ ) sum += a[i];

    return i == n && sum == ( long long int )n * ( n + 1 ) / 2;
}   

int main() 
{
    const int N = 6;        
    int t[N] = { 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1 }; 

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << g( t, N ) << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

This function will work provided that all elements of the array are different.

As for your code then this loop

```
    for(int j=n;j>0;j--){
    if(t[i]==n)
      break;
    else
      return false;
    }
```

does not make sense.

Comment: As commented in the OP, this code give a false positive with e.g.: t[6]={1,1,1,6,6,6}; : http://ideone.com/xiWaFJ

Comment: @Rama You are right. There should be appended a requirement that all elements of the array are different.:)

Answer (score 3):

My solution is giving weigths to the values, like binary digits weigths.
For example:

value `1` => weight `1` 
value `2` => weight `2` 
value `3` => weight `4` 
value `4` => weight `8` 
value `x` => weight `1 << x-1`

Then sum all of the weights, and check if satisfy `sum` = 2^n-1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

bool g( const int a[], int n )
{
    int long long sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    long long int target = (1<<n)-1;

    for ( ; i < n && a[i] > 0 ; i++ ) sum += 1<<a[i]-1;

    return i == n && sum == target;
}   

int main() 
{
    const int N = 6;        
    int t[N] = { 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1 }; 

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << g( t, N ) << std::endl;
}
```

Working code here: http://ideone.com/DscXJH

This possible solution was inspired by @lcs comment in the OP.

Comment: [Do not use `pow` for integer exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os/25678721#25678721)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks! added `round()` as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/strange-behaviour-of-the-pow-function

Comment: It's not just the rounding to watch out for. `pow` can be sickeningly expensive. In this case 2 to the `n` is awesomely easy to perform with bit shifting (`1<<n`) and it's probably done in less time than the `pow` function call overhead, not including the time spend computing the result.

Comment: @user4581301 Great! thanks, changed pow line to: `long long int target = (1<<n)-1;`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, using STL algorithm functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

bool g(int *t, int n)
{
    if ( n == 0 ) 
       return false;
    std::sort(t, t + n);
    return (t[0] == 1) &&  // first number must be 1
            (std::distance(t, std::unique(t, t + n)) == n) &&  // all must be unique
            (std::accumulate(t, t + n, 0) == (n * (n + 1)) / 2); // has to add up correctly
}

int main()
{
   int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
   std::cout << g(arr, 7);
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/B2h2MX)

After sorting the list of number, the `std::unique` algorithm function is used to move the non-unique items to the end of the array, and then give us a pointer to the start of this sequence of non-unique items.  If all the values are unique, then `std::unique` will return one position past the end of the array.

That is the reason for `std::distance` -- it tells us if the number of numbers between the beginning and the start of the non-unique sequence is equal to the number of numbers in the entire list.

The `std::accumulate` simply adds up all the numbers in the sequence, and sees if the result is `(n * (n+1)) / 2`, which is the classic formula to find the sum of the first `n` consecutive integers (starting from 1).

---

Here is an even shorter solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool g(int *t, int n)
{
    if ( n == 0 ) 
       return false;
    std::sort(t, t + n);
    return (t[0] == 1) &&  // first number must be 1
            (t[n-1] == n) && // last must be n
            (std::distance(t, std::unique(t, t + n)) == n); // all must be unique
}
```

---

Yet another approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

bool g(int *t, int n)
{
    if ( n == 0 ) 
       return false;
    std::sort(t, t + n);
    return (t[0] == 1) &&  // first number must be 1
            (t[n-1] == n) && // last must be n
            (std::set<int>(t, t+n).size() == n); // all must be unique
}

int main()
{
   int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
   std::cout << g(arr, 7);
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/B3oWSq)

In this approach, a temporary `std::set` is created from the list of numbers.  Since a `std::set` only stores unique numbers, the `size()` of the set after inserting all the items must be equal to `n` to determine if all the numbers are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Let STL do the work..  `n` is non-negative

```
#include <set>

bool g(int *t, int n)
{
    std::set<int> s {t, t+n};
    return n > 0 && s.size() == n && *s.begin() == 1 && *s.rbegin() == n;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
#include <set>

typedef int data;
typedef std::set<data> set;

template<typename Iterator>
bool g(Iterator begin, const Iterator end) {

    set elements, expected;
    data i = 1;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin, ++i) {
        elements.insert(*begin);
        expected.insert(i);
    }

    return elements == expected;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, the easiest way is to count occurences.
Initialize n+1 sized array "a" with zeros and increment a[ t[i] ].
It will exit on duplicates. Also make sure that t[i] is in valid range.

```
bool g(int* t, int n)
    {
          int* a = (int*) calloc(n+1, sizeof(int));
          for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
          {
                a[ t[i] ]++;
                if(t[i]>n || t[i]<=0 || a[ t[i] ]>1)
                      return false;
          }
          return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your function has a memory leak.

Comment: You are right. But its only to show solution for the problem