# strlen receives NULL instead of correct input

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind

I'm implementing a template vector-like class. I want my vector to operate on `int` and `Product` class, which is defined in main. It works good with `int`, but with `Product` class Valgrind reports the following:

```
==22629== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22629== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22629== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22629== Command: ./a.out
==22629== v2 = ==22629== Invalid read of size 1
==22629==    at 0x4C30F62: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22629==    by 0x4018DF: Product (main.cpp:33)
==22629==    by 0x4018DF: my_vector (my_vector.h:24)
==22629==    by 0x4018DF: void test_my_vector<Product>(Product, Product) (main.cpp:100)
==22629==    by 0x400E67: main (main.cpp:175)
==22629==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22629== 
==22629== 
==22629== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==22629==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==22629==    at 0x4C30F62: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22629==    by 0x4018DF: Product (main.cpp:33)
==22629==    by 0x4018DF: my_vector (my_vector.h:24)
==22629==    by 0x4018DF: void test_my_vector<Product>(Product, Product) (main.cpp:100)
==22629==    by 0x400E67: main (main.cpp:175)
==22629==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==22629==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==22629==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==22629==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==22629==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

Ok, it seems I pass NULL to strlen, but since I pass NULL and I don't have any `Product` constructors, which fill the `name_` field with `NULL`, it implies I have already deleted object, which is being passed to copy constructor. At least these are my thoughts.

But I don't really understand where is my mistake. Maybe it is because of inappropriate use of `placement new` or some other memory-management fault.

I also have `test_my_vector` function, which tests my vector.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <assert.h>
#include "my_vector.h"
using namespace std;
class Product {
public:
    Product(const char* name, int quantity, double price){
        name_ = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(name_, name);
        quantity_ = quantity;
        price_ = price;
    }


    Product(){
        name_ = new char[strlen("") + 1];
        strcpy(name_, "");
        quantity_ = 0;
        price_ = 0;
    }

    ~Product(){
        delete [] name_;
    }

    Product(const Product& other){
        price_ = other.price_;
        quantity_ = other.quantity_;
        name_ = new char[strlen(other.name_) + 1];
        strcpy(name_, other.name_);
    };

    const Product& operator=(const Product& other){
        delete [] name_; 
        price_ = other.price_;
        quantity_ = other.quantity_;
        name_ = new char[strlen(other.name_) + 1];
        strcpy(name_, other.name_);
        return other;
    };


private:
    char* name_;
    int quantity_;
    double price_; 
};



template <typename T>  
void test_my_vector(T t1, T t2){
   //some asserts
}

int main() {
    test_my_vector<int>(5, 10);
    test_my_vector<Product>(Product("asdf", 4, 12.0), Product("qwe", -1, 7.5));
    return 0;
 }
```

And my_vector.h

```
template <class T>
class my_vector{
public:
my_vector(){
    capacity_ = 0;
    size_ = 0;
    array_ = NULL;
};

my_vector(const size_t n){
    size_ = n;
    capacity_ = (size_t) pow(2, ceil(log(n)/log(2)));
    array_ = (T*)(new char[sizeof(T) * capacity_]());
};

my_vector(const my_vector<T>& other){
    size_ = other.size_;
    capacity_ = other.capacity_;
    array_ = (T*)(new char[sizeof(T) * capacity_]);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size_; i++)
        new (&array_[i]) T(other.array_[i]), std::cout << i;
};

my_vector<T>& operator=(const my_vector<T>& other){
    this -> ~my_vector();
    size_ = other.size_;
    capacity_ = other.capacity_;
    array_ = (T*)(new char[sizeof(T) * capacity_]);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size_; i++)
        new (&array_[i]) T(other.array_[i]);;
    return *this;
};

~my_vector(){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size_; i++)
        array_[i].~T();
    delete [] (char*) array_;
};



void resize(const size_t n){
    reserve(n);
    size_ = n;
};

void reserve(const size_t n){
    if (n > capacity_){
        if(!capacity_) capacity_ = 1;
        while(capacity_ < n)
            capacity_ *= 2;
        T* new_array = (T*)(new char[sizeof(T) * capacity_]);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; i++)
            new (&new_array[i]) T(array_[i]);;
        this -> ~my_vector();
        array_ = new_array;
    }
};


void push_back(const T& t){
    if (!capacity_)
        reserve(2);
    else if(size_ == capacity_)
        reserve(2 * capacity_);
    new (&array_[size_]) T(t);
    size_++;
};

private:
   size_t capacity_;
   size_t size_;
   T* array_;
};
```

Comment: Only post code that is relevant to your question, please.

Comment: Please follow [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that someone might actually comprehend what's going on

Comment: `Product` does not correctly handle self-assignment

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I have reduced the code snippet, sorry.

Comment: @Felix192 Why not just use the [copy / swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for your assignment operators?  You're reimplementing your copy constructor, when you should be using it to your advantage.

Comment: Product's `operator=` is broken. It should be returning a non-const `*this`. Additionally, [pow() does not work the way you think it works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/strange-behaviour-of-the-pow-function).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was using this concept in my previous versions, but then I decided to change it  I don't know even why(may be to do memory-mangement more explicitly)... Can I do just `swap(*this, other);`?

Comment: @Felix192 *may be to do memory-management more explicitly* -- Why did you change it?  You are already doing the memory management explicitly, in the copy constructor -- with copy / swap, all you're doing is reusing it.

Comment: `pow(2, ceil(log(n)/log(2)))` why so complex? `1 << log2(n)` would be much faster and more elegant. Use a fast `log2` inplementation from [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious)

Comment: @Felix192 -- Your `test_my_vector` function doesn't test `my_vector` at all.  It is an empty template function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What do you mean by empty? I deleted the body, because it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Felix192 Your error [cannot be duplicated](http://ideone.com/zzHDJu).  It is not irrelevant.  How can you post it, and it is not used at all in your sample program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First error:**  Your `my_vector` constructor does not create objects.  All it does is initialize the memory for the objects, but doesn't construct them.  What winds up happening is that subsequent copy operations are working with invalid objects.

The correction is below:

```
my_vector(const size_t n)
{
    size_ = n;
    capacity_ = (size_t)pow(2, ceil(log(n) / log(2)));
    array_ = (T*)(new char[sizeof(T) * capacity_]());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; i++)
        new (&array_[i]) T();  // default construct objects
};
```

In addition, I don't recommend using `pow` if you're going to use integer exponents.  The link in the comments, [plus this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os) shows what can happen when using `pow` for integer calculations.

**Second error:**  Your assignment operators are incorrect in that they do not check for self assignment.  Save yourself all of that trouble and use the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for your assignment operator:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
Product& operator=(const Product& other)
{
    Product temp(other);
    std::swap(temp.name_, name_);
    std::swap(temp.price, price);
    std::swap(temp.quantity_, quantity_);
    return *this;
}
```

The same thing can be done with `my_vector`:

```
my_vector<T>& operator=(const my_vector<T>& other)
{
    my_vector<T> temp(other);
    std::swap(temp.size_, size_);
    std::swap(temp.capacity_, capacity_);
    std::swap(temp.array_, array_);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `temp` instead of `other` in the first case. Anyways it gives no result, there is still an invalid read of size 1... At least now it fails after `size_` iterations of for loop in copy constructor.

Comment: Then fix your copy constructor.  The advantage of writing your assignment operators this way is that it tests whether your copy constructor is actually working correctly (as well as destructor).  Once you get your copy constructor working correctly, then the assignment operator above will automatically work correctly.