# Armstrong number in c programming

Tags: c

I made a program in C to find whether an integer is an [Armstrong number](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html) or not for three digits numbers. If the number that has been given by the user is an Armstrong number it will print `it is an armstrong number` and if it is not an Armstrong number it will print `its not an armstrong number`. It is not showing any errors. Also it works with all three digit numbers except for a number. It is `153`. It is printing that it is not an Armstrong number even though it is an Armstrong number. Could anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Here is the code and output:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int sum = 0;
    int n;

    //asking the user to enter a number
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // copying the value of n in a variable b
    int b = n;

    while (n != 0) {
        // storing the reminders of n divided by 10 in a variable
        int r = n % 10;
    
        // finding the power 
        sum = pow(r, 3) + sum;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    // here I am printing the sum just to show you guys what is the answer i am getting
    printf("%d\n", sum);

    // if sum equals to b, then do this
    if (sum == b) {
        printf("The number is an armstrong number\n");
    }
    // if not then do this
    else {
        printf("It is not an armstrong number\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the output I am getting if I enter a three digit Armstrong number:

```
Enter a number : 370
370
The number is an armstrong number

Enter a number : 407
407
The number is an armstrong number
```

Here I am entering a number which is not an armstrong number:

```
Enter a number : 100
1
It is not an armstrong number
```

`153` is an Armstrong number. Here is what happens when I enter 153:

```
Enter a number : 153
152
It is not an armstrong number
```

It is saying `153 is not a armstrong number`. Why does this happen?
How can I solve this?

Comment: I think your problem, regarding the inaccuracies of pow and floating point, is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/strange-behaviour-of-the-pow-function)

Answer (score 3):

The `pow` implementation in your standard C library is deficient and returns an approximation even when the mathematical result is exactly representable.

Stop using it for cubes. Replace `pow(r,3)` with `r*r*r`.

Comment: The problem is that `pow` is a floating-point function which by its very nature is imprecise. Sometimes rounding error might, for example, make `pow(5,3(` come out to 124.99999999999, which, when converted back to an integer, becomes 124 instead of 125. This solution is correct.

Comment: @SGeorgiades: No, that is not the problem. It is entirely possible to implement `pow` so that it returns exactly correct results for representable values. For example, the macOS `pow` implementation does that. Saying this is the problem is like saying you should expect the integer `/` operator to be wrong because it is by its very nature imprecise: It must truncate `7/3` to 2, therefore you should expect `9/3` to be wrong. That is an incorrect argument; the fact that some mathematical results cannot be represented does not mean others must be calculated incorrectly.

Comment: @SGeorgiades: The explanation is as I stated in the answer: The `pow` implementation in OP’s standard C library is deficient. Microsoft’s `pow` implementation was known to have this deficiency in previous versions (maybe in some current software; I do not know what they have deployed currently). There is no mathematical reason for this; it is an implementation choice about what results to deliver. It is **not** the “very nature” of the function. It is an implementation choice.

Comment: Are you saying that it is the problem of operating system

Comment: @NAVANEETHJNAIR Its not an issue with the operating system. its the compilers how they implement that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working on gcc compilers.
check for yourself
https://godbolt.org/z/Pvo19xrxx

as mentioned by others use `r*r*r` instead of pow.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this when we want to change the number of digits. For example this code is only for 3 digits. If i want to find 4 digits armstrong we need to change r×r×r to r×r×r×r. I was asking is there anyway you can do this without doing like this. With permanent code.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/78hjK6x7z

Comment: Ok Thanks. Now I understood

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

int main(){

    int num;
    printf("Please enter a three digit number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    //Taking input
    int a = (num - (num % 100) );
    int hu = a/100;
    //Finding hundreds digit
    int b = num - a - (num % 10) ;
    int te = b/10;
    //Finding tens digit
    int un = num - a - b;
    //Finding units digit
    printf("hu = %d\n", hu);
    printf("te = %d\n", te);
    printf("un = %d\n", un);
    //Conditional forms
    //Use of pow is allowed through math.h header file
    if(num == pow(hu, 3) + pow(te,3)+ pow(un, 3)){
        printf("The entered number is an armstrong number");
    }
    else if(num != pow(hu, 3) + pow(te,3), pow(un, 3)){
        printf("The entered number is not an armstrong number");
    }   
}
```

Comment: No explanation and likely not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably linked to the implementation of the `pow()` function on your system.  Unless the implementors made a special case of integral arguments, `pow(x, n)` can be computed as `exp(log(x) * n)` which may produce a result that is just slightly less than the expected integral result because `log(5)` cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number (ie: `124,999999999999` instead of `125`). Conversion to `int` is performed as truncation of the fractional part, hence `124` instead of `125`.

Different implementations may produce slightly different results depending on how they handle integral arguments.  This explains why you observe a problem and other people on different systems do not.

There are 2 ways to avoid this pitfall:

- use `round(pow(r, 3))` to ensure the result is the closest integer in case it is not already the expected integer.
- use `r * r * r` which is performed with integer arithmetics.

Here is a modified version with the latter approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int n = 0;

    //asking the user to enter a number
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    // copying the value of n in a temporary variable b
    int b = n;
    int sum = 0;

    while (n != 0) {
        // storing the reminders of n divided by 10 in a variable
        int r = b % 10;
    
        // finding the power 
        sum = r * r * r + sum;
        b = b / 10;
    }
    // here I am printing the sum just to show you guys what is the answer I am getting
    printf("%d\n", sum);

    // if sum equals to b, then do this
    if (sum == n) {
        printf("The number is an armstrong number\n");
    } else {
        // if not then do this
        printf("It is not an armstrong number\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int no=153,r=0,t;
    t=no;
    while(no>0){
        r=r+(no%10)*(no%10)*(no%10);
        no=no/10;
    }
    if(t==r){
        printf("The number is a Armstrong number");
    }else{
        printf("The number is not an Armstrong number");
    }
    return 0;
}
```