# Why is Codeblock calculation wrong?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I run my code in Codeblock vs an online ide and the solution is different ?

- I input x =5 and n = 3, CodeBlock calculation is sum =c153 and an online Ide (https://www.online-ide.com/) give out sum = 155
  .What is the problem here ?

[image: online IDE]

[image: Codeblocks]

**My code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout<<"Calculate x + x^2 + x^3 +...+ x^n"<<endl<<endl;

    //Input
    int x,n;
    cout<<"Input x ";cin>>x;
    cout<<"Input n ";cin>>n;


    //Calculation
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i =1 ; i<=n; i++)
    {
        sum += pow(x,i);
    }


    //Output
    cout<<"The sum is  "<<sum;

    return 0;



}
```

Comment: `pow` is a floating point calculation. It won't always be exact and when assigned to an integer it truncates the result. [Strange behaviour of the pow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/strange-behaviour-of-the-pow-function)

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.