# How can I check that a bit is set (without bitwise operation)?

Tags: javascript, math, bit-manipulation

Looking at the int 44 — I need `Math.CEIL (log(2) 44)` of binary places to represent `44`. 
(answer is 6 places)

6 places :

```
___  ___  ___  ___  ___   ___
32   16    8    4    2     1
```

But how can I check that (for example) the bit of `8` is checked or not ?

A simple solution will be do to :

`((1<<3) & 44)>0`  so this will check if the bit is set.

But please notice that behind the scenes the computer translates `44` to its binary representation  and just check if bit is set via bitwise operation.

Another solution is just to build the binary myself via `toString(2)` or `mod%2` in a loop

**Question**

<strike>*Mathematically*</strike> Via which formula,   I can test if `n'th` bit is set ?

(I would prefer a non loop operation but pure single math phrase)

Comment: *Mathematically*, there are no spoons - erm, I mean bits.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, but what wrong with bitwise operation?  why you want avoid it?

Comment: :) But still – "the computer translates 44 to its binary representation and just check if bit is set via bitwise operation", no, that is mixing metaphors (or maybe just techniques). "The n'th bit" **is** a bitwise operation. This is the same as checking the value of "the n'th decimal" in a large decimal number (and for any other base). I'm pretty sure you'll need something like a mod and a div somewhere.

Comment: Any hint *why* you don't want binary operations? This is the most efficient way of operating on bits (way more efficient than `toString` or `%`). Alternately, you can use `log`, as you obviously know.

Comment: @Amadan I'm building a tinyURL like generator so I have `abc..ABC...0..9` which is 26+26+10 which is 62 options so it's base 62. now , after I have the number to encode (44) and I have the number of places . but now iterating through each place I need to knowif there's vlue and what is the value

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you have a fixed number set? like from 1 to 100?

Comment: Instead of 2 options in base 2 I have 62 options .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'bit' (actually *any* base) value of an indexed number *index* in a value *val* in base *base* can in general be calculated as

```
val = 1966;
index = 2;
base = 10;
alert (Math.floor(val/Math.pow(base,index)) % base);
```

result: `9`

```
val = 44;
index = 3;
base = 2;
alert (Math.floor(val/Math.pow(base,index)) % base);
```

result: `1` (only `0` and `1` are possible here – the range will always be `0..base-1`).

The combination of `Math.floor` (to coerce to an integer in Javascript) and `Math.pow` is kind of iffy here. Even in integer range, `Math.pow` may generate a floating point number *slightly* below the expected 'whole' number. Perhaps it is safer to always add a small constant:

```
alert (Math.floor(0.1+val/Math.pow(base,index)) % base);
```

Comment: In what scenarios would 0.1 help ? can you supply example ?

Comment: Read [Understanding floating point problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4664662/2564301) (and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), mentioned in one of the answers). Javascript doesn't "do" real integers. Also, `Math.pow` is a pure floating point operation, and as such it *may* be inaccurate. (I just tested for some random ranges and didn't find an example–still, it may depend on the JS engine.)

Comment: Read it many times to mention. But I was hoping that you supply an example that will support that `0.1` floor helper.

Comment: @Royi: sorry, I just tested `1..35` for both base and exponent - found not one! :) But [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.pow) is vague on this: "... an implementation-dependent approximation ..." The idea of using `0.1`, by the way, is that the epsilon is somewhere in the order of 10⁻⁴. See for example [C's pow() function as per header file <math.h> not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3509423/2564301) for C.

Answer (score 10):

Divide by the value of the bit that you want to check
and test if the first bit is set (this can be tested with `x mod 2 == 1`)

Math expression:

```
floor(value/(2^bitPos)) mod 2 = 1
```

As JS function:

```
function isSet(value, bitPos) {
   var result =   Math.floor(value / Math.pow(2, bitPos)) % 2;
   return result == 1;
}
```

Note: bitPos starts with 0 (bit representing the nr 1)

Comment: To test 3'rd bit `Math.floor((44)/(2^2)) % 2` NaN

Comment: @RoyiNamir, for power, use `Math.pow`, if I'm not mistaken `2^2` is `2 xor 2`

Comment: Test case 44 returns:
isSet(44,5) == true; 
isSet(44,4) == false;
isSet(44,3) == true;
isSet(44,2) == true;
isSet(44,1) == false;
isSet(44,0) == false;

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the `bit` at the position is set to `1`.

```
function isBitSet(no, index) {
    var bin = no.toString(2);
    // Convert to Binary

    index = bin.length - index;
    // Reverse the index, start from right to left

    return bin[index] == 1;
}
isBitSet(44, 2); // Check if second bit is set from left
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/e4zrqt71/)